# Resources on blended teaching and flipped classroom in undergraduate mathematics education

Tags: teaching

I'd like to learn about the implementation of "blended teaching" in general and "flipped classroom" in particular for the teaching of undergraduate mathematics. Can anyone recommend some good resources?

Comment: Possibly more appropriate for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of resources. A good place to start would be Googling the buzzwords:

- Active learning
- Flipped classroom
- Inquiry-based learning
- Think-pair-share
- Jigsaw
- Clickers
- etc.

An alternative approach would be to check out [this well-known paper by Freeman et. al.](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1319030111) about how active learning beats lecturing (in terms of student learning and retention), then look at the papers it cites, then [look on Google scholar to see who cites it](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?cites=4287590615081130165&as_sdt=5,36&sciodt=0,36&hl=en).

Yet another approach is to browse a journal on undergraduate math education, like [PRIMUS](https://primusmath.com/) (also, its attached blog).

Lastly, there are tons of conferences where you can learn more, like those advertised [here](http://www.inquirybasedlearning.org/). There's even a Fellowship you can apply for, to become a [Project NExT Fellow](https://www.maa.org/programs-and-communities/professional-development/project-next) and get mentorship to move your teaching in the direction of active learning.